# Remove space of list component in jasper ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

i want to remove list component space when the data is null, i have tried (remove line when blank) option but there is no use, it is printing the space with height of list component.
thanks help is needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="List" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="179e723d-ee8c-40bf-9ef6-914cef106c9a">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="005448a6-5d6c-44c5-b063-7e85cdcd0cfe"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset2" uuid="d8b4d679-e011-4828-adc5-cc0feeea6b44"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="5" y="13" width="797" height="88" uuid="d03a66cd-2364-4705-b9c1-7ccdc1f03542"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1" uuid="55af5621-ba24-4f19-8c1d-496627ce93c6">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="88" width="797">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="22" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3a8c6a5e-2337-40b6-9464-984655b240c1"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Parent List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="186" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3961e703-a32a-4c98-98fc-5b5fd745962a"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Parent List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="350" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="c75ef0b2-9d7b-4d53-89a9-60407300b1f5"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Parent List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="797" height="26" uuid="3a0c69f8-788d-4e30-b9ab-3a5a7e6847b2"/>
                            <jr:list>
                                <datasetRun subDataset="dataset2" uuid="109058e7-c925-4ab2-ae35-4d71a8868623">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="26" width="797">
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement x="20" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="528cdfee-2066-4c73-bfa4-01c71368e999"/>
                                        <text><![CDATA[child List]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement x="190" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="3187542d-7f8d-4770-9d84-0a0a5ee2c841"/>
                                        <text><![CDATA[Child List]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="24" y="52" width="100" height="20" uuid="83d4dfff-8142-4e20-a929-e37a23ea2c20"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having all the `list` components inside `Frame` component and enable `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` to `rue` to all the components including `Frame` component. Below is just a sample

```
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="124" y="114" width="393" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="69f3030b-5ff6-4689-aa2f-d929dc017fc4"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="5" y="13" width="797" height="88" uuid="d03a66cd-2364-4705-b9c1-7ccdc1f03542"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1" uuid="55af5621-ba24-4f19-8c1d-496627ce93c6">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="88" width="797">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="22" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3a8c6a5e-2337-40b6-9464-984655b240c1"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Parent List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="186" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="3961e703-a32a-4c98-98fc-5b5fd745962a"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Parent List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="350" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="c75ef0b2-9d7b-4d53-89a9-60407300b1f5"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Parent List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="797" height="26" uuid="3a0c69f8-788d-4e30-b9ab-3a5a7e6847b2"/>
                            <jr:list>
                                <datasetRun subDataset="dataset2" uuid="109058e7-c925-4ab2-ae35-4d71a8868623">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="26" width="797">
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement x="20" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="528cdfee-2066-4c73-bfa4-01c71368e999"/>
                                        <text><![CDATA[child List]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement x="190" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="3187542d-7f8d-4770-9d84-0a0a5ee2c841"/>
                                        <text><![CDATA[Child List]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="24" y="52" width="100" height="20" uuid="83d4dfff-8142-4e20-a929-e37a23ea2c20"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Hope this should help you out.